# Fill column with numbers with 4 visible digits based on row

Tags: excel, vba

In the column `AS`, I have a blank column where I need to give a number to each row starting from row 3 to the last row (this is already predefined as lastrow(row number) in the VBA). Is there any way to number them from 1 to the last row in VBA programming?

For example, in the Column `AS` i would like to have

```
Row 3: 1
Row 4: 2
Row 5: 3
....
Last Row: XXX
```

If possible, how do you format the numbers so that they are all 4 digits

```
0001,
0002,
0003,
etc
```

Comment: Are you okay with the numbers being stored as text?

Comment: @MatthewD, I think you can also use `Range.NumberFormat = "0000"`

Answer (score 2):

MatthewD's code is fine, but my `.NumberFormat` method is a little cleaner, and I don't use the problematic `UsedRange`.

```
Sub M1FourDigitRow()
'
' M1FourDigitRow Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+Q
'
Dim Range1 As Range
Dim Cell1 As Range

Set Range1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet9").Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet9").Cells(3, "AS"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet9").Cells(1000, "AS"))
For Each Cell1 In Range1
    Cell1.Value = Cell1.Row - 2
    Cell1.NumberFormat = "0000"
Next Cell1

End Sub
```

Comment: Great solution.  I have never had a problem with usedrange though.  Here you are limiting him to having 1000 rows.  Could be more dynamic.

Comment: I assumed he would change it to whatever row count suited him :) UsedRange can be shaky, I'd recommend `xlEndUp` if you know that one.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCount as Long
Dim ws as excel.worksheet
Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet
Dim strCount As String

    lRow = 3
    lCount  = 1
    Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

    strCount = Trim(str(lCount))
    If Len(strCount) = 1 Then
        ws.Range("AS" & lRow).Value = "'000" & strCount
    ElseIf Len(strCount) = 2 Then
        ws.Range("AS" & lRow).Value = "'00" & strCount
    ElseIf Len(strCount) = 3 Then
        ws.Range("AS" & lRow).Value = "'0" & strCount
    Else
         ws.Range("AS" & lRow).Value = "'" & strCount
    End If

    lCount = lCount + 1
    lRow = lRow + 1
    Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a much better solution that what's been offered. Excel has a `Fill Series` feature that can perform trends and linear progressions. It's a simple one-line function call to `DataSeries()` in VBA:

```
Range("AS3") = 1                             ' Set the starting value

With Range("AS3:AS" & intLastRow)
    .DataSeries xlColumns, xlLinear, , 1     ' Linear series, step = 1
    .NumberFormat = "0000"                   ' Pad with zeros
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to give you the numbers as text and without looping:

```
Range("AS3:AS" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).formula = "=Right(""000"" & Row(AS3) - 2,4)"
Range("AS:AS").copy
Range("AS:AS").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Uses the `ROW()` function in excel then copies and pastes as values.

Assumes you have data in column B